# Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac - subfolders missing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

I currently categorize many of my e-mails into subfolders inside folders on Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac. Trouble is, in past couple weeks, the subfolders seem to have disappeared. No little arrows to expand folders either.

The emails are still there, because I can locate them using Finder.

But I can't actually access the subfolders themselves.

Does anyone know what might cause this, or how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Outlook for Mac, there's a preference to "Hide on My Computer Folders" (Outlook/Preferences/General).  Un-check that box and your email sub-folders will re-appear.